# Error running linux command from java

Tags: java, linux, git, repo

I am trying to run the below command from java code using `Process process =Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)` but getting the error.

Command: `repo forall -c 'pwd;git status'`

Error:`'pwd;git: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching`''`
I am able to run this command from linux terminal but when running from java the problem is with the space after pwd;git. Can anyone help me?

Comment: "I am able to run this command from linux terminal" <-- A `Process` _is not_ a command interpreter! What is more, don't use `Runtime.exec()`, use a `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: @fge: Do you mean I am getting this errir because of using Runtime.exec()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an ultra classical mistake and I am frankly surprised that you didn't find the answer to it by searching around.

**A `Process` is not a command interpreter.**

However, `Runtime.exec()` will still try and act as one if you pass it only one argument, and here you'll end up splitting like this:

- `repo`
- `forall`
- `-c`
- `'pwd;git`
- `status'`

Which is obviously not what you want.

Use a `ProcessBuilder`. I won't do it all for you but here is how to start:

```
final Process p = new ProcessBuilder()
    .command("repo", "forall", "-c", "pwd; git status")
    // etc etc
    .start();
```

[Link to the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).